# Oracle. How do I select first row in a group

Tags: plsql

I have data (SELECT * FROM t) that looks like that

```
ID | VERSION | ...
====================
1  |    2    | ...
1  |    1    | ...
2  |    3    | ...
2  |    2    | ...
2  |    1    | ...
....
```

How can I take only the first row (with maximum version) for every unique ID value ?

```
ID | VERSION | ...
====================
1  |    2    | ...
2  |    3    | ...
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row_number analytic function to rank rows per ID column, then filter out only rows with rnb = 1 :

```sql
select *
from (
select t.*, row_number()over(partition by ID order by VERSION desc) rnb
from Your_table t
)
where rnb = 1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select t.ID, MAX(t.version) as version from t
group by t.ID
```

note: version is a reserved word, so i advise to chose some other column name.

---

for all results :

```
select *
  from t
 where (t.ID, t.version) in
       (select t.ID, MAX(t.version) as version from t group by t.ID)
```

Comment: Oh, and what about other columns (that are skipped for brevity as ...), is it ok to group them too?

Comment: @user149691 i added another query to my answer for select all columns